# Ruby Hash by default get sorted in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I am using ruby 1.8.7 on a production server and my hash get automatically get sorted while assigning it to variable. and in local machine its working fine.

This is output taken from my production console

```
>> a = {"b" => "a", "a" => "c"}

=> {"a"=>"c", "b"=>"a"}

>> a

=> {"a"=>"c", "b"=>"a"}
>>
```

Have any ideas? How do I avoid sorting of hash?

Thanks

Comment: In fact the hash is not sorted by default, but iterated in the most convenient order for Ruby 1.8.7. This behaviour changed in 1.9+, which iterates keys in the order inserted to the hash. You cannot change this, but may work-around it where it is important (provided your requirement is *not* simply to use insertion order, but just a well-defined order)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't / can't. If your script relies on some specific ordering, then you most likely want to use a list of key/value pairs instead. When using a hash in 1.8, the order is not defined in the specification. When using 1.9 it is defined to enumerate in the insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

`Hash` in 1.8.7 isn't ordered, meaning you cannot rely on the order of the key-value pairs. That you're seeing them sorted alphanumerically is a coincidence.

If you need to know the order of the key/value pairs, you can use [`ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash) (or upgrade to Ruby 1.9+ and use the builtin `Hash`).